# Translation of Borel's generalization of Picard's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, translation-request

Does anyone have English translation of Borel's generalization of Picard's(little) Theorem? The French version can be found [here](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/acta-mathematica/volume-20/issue-none/Sur-les-z%C3%A9ros-des-fonctions-enti%C3%A8res/10.1007/BF02418037.full?tab=ArticleFirstPage) on page 26. Thank you. Or else it would also help me if someone could at-least give me the statement of the generalization and give a brief sketch of the proof.